# Localhost showing nginx instead of apache

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed XAMPP on Ubuntu 14.04. Whenever I run localhost, it shows me nginx page instead of apache. How can I run apache apps?

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: You cannot "run" `localhost` and there are no "apache apps". You need to get your things straight, to understand how things work. So: if you operate _two_ http servers at the same time then only one can bind to port `80`. It should be the first one that gets started, the second one will fail to start unless configured to use another port. So do not start nginx before apache if you want to use apache with the URL `http://localhost/`.

Comment: Thanks. I had another port (8080) that I had used in the XAMPP configuration. I have used that to open localhost and it worked. Can you guys post it as an answer so it can be selected? Thanks.

Comment: Nginx listens for [::]:80 by default, and localhost is resolved with ipv6 adress. Try direct ipv4 address, or turn off nginx.

Answer (score 2):

You can get which daemon is listening on port 80 by issuing this command:

```
lsof -i :80
```

The result will be something like:

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   24937     root   42u  IPv4 3198958      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   24937     root   43u  IPv6 3198959      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

In this case you can see that the daemon is **nginx**.
Once you're sure that nginx is listening on port 80 you have to stop it before starting apache on that port

```
service nginx stop
```

Now you can start (or restart) XAMPP and check if apache is listening on port 80 (same lsof command).

If you want to disable nginx from starting on boot then you'll have to issue this command

```
update-rc.d nginx disable
```

Or you can uninstall nginx from your system using

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx
```